# How could the naruto-running titan zombies' insanely fast regeneration be explained?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, zombies

**Note:** !"*string*" means not "*string*", i.e: !"N-word" means: *not (the) N-word*. The "titan" adjective refers to titans from the anime, Shingeki no Kyojin, who possessed a similarly powerful healing factor and were also [seen naruto-running on an occasion](https://youtu.be/pV5WnfGMlK4?t=13).

Naruto-running titan zombies are the most important part of the world. They're so dangerous the !"Shout", that creates them, was kept a secret by !"Alduin" and !"Paarthurnax", both of whom refused to use it even when they faced certain death. The rest of the cast theorized on whether  the words "anime", "forever", "heal" and several others were missing from the draconic language on purpose, as !"Shouts" that had regeneration as an effect weren't using an actual word for it, and instead relied on function calls, present in mortal magic. But what could such an incredibly powerful !"Shout" do?

**!"Shout" name:** [All Dead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkddZc4v15)
**!"Shout" user:** Timmy, the Power Gamer; formerly !"Alduin" and !"Paarthurnax"
**Words:** (Anime) (Forever) (Heal/Recover)

**Ability:** Turn human corpses into naruto-running titan zombies. You may control them through wireless connection. Be aware, the system cannot handle too many connections. You may create default behavior profiles for zombies, not present on the network.

Naruto-running titan zombies are humanoid creatures with features resembling the human they originated from. Almost all naruto-running titan zombies possess physical deformations, albeit never ones that'd hinder their intended goal.

Naruto-running titan zombies are pretty agile but not particularly strong by human standards, and an experienced soldier can reasonably overpower one. Their greatest power is the insane amount of damage they can sustain and the time it takes for them to heal from. A naruto-running titan zombie can (given enough material) regrow an entire limb under a minute. The only way to permanently kill a naruto-running titan zombie is by destroying the brain, however:

Injecting a naruto-running titan zombie's corpse, or any human corpse for that matter, with the spinal fluid of any naruto-running titan zombie causes it to be resurrected. Severed body parts, injected separately, will turn into complete zombies, which would have made naruto-running titan zombies the first multi-celled organisms to asexually reproduce, if Reddit mods didn't exist.

**Now, naruto-running titan zombies resemble humans from the outside, their inside is up to your imagination.**

A lot depends on naruto-running titan zombies' regenerative abilities, as it ultimately decides wheter I can use them as a magical WMD or not?

**How could the naruto-running titan zombies' insanely fast regeneration  be explained in a scientifically plausible way?**

Comment: I love how much I hate this.

Comment: @ITAlex You gotta explain that.

Comment: Insanely fast regeneration is practically never scientifically plausible and you're almost always better resorting to magic or soft sci-fi. Also, we need to ban you from using the phrase 'naruto-running titan'.

Comment: @sphennings No, it does not. Titan zombies can be much more bizarre, so the constraints of these question are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 0):

**Nanobots**

In modern sci-fi, nanobots have became to be known as almost all-powerful solution to a number of problems. They are fast, they are tough and are able to build and repair things that normally take long time to assemble. Given enough power and biological material, they indeed are capable of rebuilding a missing limb in less than a minute.

However, in this particular case nanobots require direction from a central command unit, which resides in creature's brain. The question as where the nanobots are getting power to sustain themselves is still open, but I'm sure it can be resolved, if specifically investigated.

Comment: I don't like saying this in the main body (of the question) but OTR I say I thought about making titan zombies basically smart liquids... but that led to some problems.

Comment: @Mephistopheles fewer problems than those required to break all the inconvenient molecular bonds in a human body's worth of ambient material and then promptly reform them to build a human. If your magical nanobots ever caught fire they'd go up like a nuclear bomb, they'd need so much energy.

Comment: The main problem with the liquid solution was the strength. They don't need to be particularly strong, just strong enough to use a sword or a shield, the skill of veteran soldiers would easily be overcome by the number of their assailants.

Comment: @Mephistopheles strength like material strength? you've already handwaved in utility fog to your setting; a dense cloud of foglets all hanging on to each other could have a pretty substantial strength dictated by the structure and number of their interlinking hooks. Mechanical linkages can mimic muscle movement and can be as strong as you're prepared to handwave (though constrained by the aforementioned material limits, etc).